# Live/Extract: How to change Tabelau data source connection from live to extract on the server?

Tags: tableau-api

I created a tableau report, with **custom SQL query**, and used a live connection to connect to my database. **I have published a tableau report**. Is there a way to change the connection now to extract, via browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to publish without extract and change it from live to extract online.

I [created an empty extract instead and populated it online](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2013/9/easy-empty-local-extracts-25152) as a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such option. You have to create a local extract first and then publish it to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.